# Configuring MySQL using command prompt and MySQLInstanceConfig.exe

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install and configure MySQL (version 4.1.22 on Windows XP) using the command prompt silently so it can be included within an installer for a different application. I thought I had everything installed and configured correctly but the MySQL service fails to start, even if I try to start it through the services snap-in.

I am currently doing the following:

1. mysql-essential-4.1.22-win32.msi /passive
2. MySQLInstanceConfig.exe -i -q "-lc:mysql_install_log.txt" ServerType=DEVELOPMENT DatabaseType=MIXED ConnectionUsage=DSS Port=3306 RootPassword=password

I get no errors or anything that would indicate the parameters are incorrect, the only indication of a problem is within the mysql_install_log.txt which says (See full log below):

- *Could not start the service MySQL. Error: 0*

As far as I can see MySQL has all the configuration it needs and all paths referred to in the install log exit etc.  I have also tried to configure using MySQLInstanceConfig.exe using the UI and that works fine.

This error is obviously referring to some missing configuration, what is it that I am missing?

Also please note:

- I cannot upgrade to a newer version of MySQL
- I am running this on a brand new Windows XP SP3 installation in a virtual machine
- I am using the MySQLInstanceConfig parameters as defined [here](http://svn.mysql.com/svnpublic/mysql-instance-config/trunk/readme.txt)

The full install log:

---

Welcome to the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard 1.0.8
Date: 2009-08-08 14:10:45

Installing service ...

Product Name:         MySQL Server 4.1
Version:              4.1.22
Installation Path:    C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\

Creating configuration file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\my.ini using template C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\my-template.ini.
Options:
DEVELOPMENT
MIXED
DSS
STRICTMODE

Variables:
port: 3306
default-character-set: latin1
basedir: "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 4.1/"
datadir: "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 4.1/Data/"

Creating Windows service entry.
Service Name: "MySQL"
Parameters:   "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\my.ini" MySQL.
Windows service MySQL installed.
Could not start the service MySQL. Error: 0

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is ancient, and you've probably long ago found an answer, but hopefully this info might still be useful to someone.

I had this same problem with MySQL v5.1, and couldn't solve it in a good way.  I ended up manually installing the service directly after running the config instance wizard.

e.g.

```
mysqld --install NameOfYourMySQLService --defaults-file=your_ini_file.ini
```

then manually starting the service, which I did through C# using the following code (except all the ugly retry stuff snipped to protect my fragile pride)

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices("127.0.0.1");
foreach (ServiceController service in services)
{
    if (service.ServiceName == "NameOfYourMySQLService ")
    {
        service.Start();
    }
}
```

or if you're doing it in a batch file just

```
net start NameOfYourMySQLService
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create folder **C:\MYSQL**
2. Download **mysql-installer-community-5.6.20.0.msi** from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-community-5.6.20.0.msi) and save it to **C:\MYSQL** folder.
3. Create batch file with name **installer.bat** in **C:\MYSQL**. Copy bellow script to     **installer.bat**:

   @echo off

   msiexec /i "%~dp0\mysql-installer-community-5.6.20.0.msi" /quiet

   "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Installer\MySQLInstallerConsole.exe" --action=install --product=mysql-server-5.6-win32 --product=connector-net-win32 --config=mysql-server-5.6-win32:passwd=your_password;autostartservice=true;openfirewall=true;port=3306;
4. Running **installer.bat**

Script above will do the following:

- Install mysql-server-5.6-win32 with username=root, password=your_password
- Install .NET Connector
- Start Mysql Service
- Add MySql port 3306 to firewall

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer above - but actually working (for 5.6.27 at least)

1. Create a temporary folder
2. Put in the folder the mysql-installer-community-[version].msi
3. Create the following batch file. Replace the version variable with the version you downloaded

```
if '%1' == '' goto usage

set password=%1
set installer="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\MySQLInstallerConsole.exe"
set "version=5.6.27"
msiexec /i "%~dp0\mysql-installer-community-%version%.0.msi" /quiet

%installer% install server;%version%;X64:*:port=3307;openfirewall=true;passwd=%password% -silent

goto finally

:usage
echo. 
echo MySQL server install script
echo. 
echo Usage %0 [root password]
echo. 
goto finally

:finally
```

4. Run the batch file - add the root password as a parameter

   installer.bat [root_password]